# Caching Database Query - remember

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

**I am using Caching Database Queries. My code is below.**

```
$Categories = \App\Models\Skill\Category_Model::paginate(1)->remember(60);
```

Then I got the below runtime error.

> Method remember does not exist.

**Am I missing something ?**

Comment: Don't think "remember" is a part of Laravel 5. [This](https://github.com/dwightwatson/rememberable) seems to back it up and possibly solve your problem.

Comment: Where did you find code that suggests calling remember on a query result?

Comment: I am not sure if this is right way to do Database Query Caching. What's the best way to cache Database queries in Laravel 5.1 ?

Answer (score 2):

`remember` used to be part of Eloquent before at 4.2 but with the new Laravel now it's part of caching itself.

As I quote from Laravel documentation in this [link](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/upgrade#upgrade-5.0):

> Eloquent Caching
>
> Eloquent no longer provides the **remember** method for caching queries.
>   You now are responsible for caching your queries manually using the
>   `Cache::remember` function. For more information on caching, consult the
>   [full documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/cache).

Answering your question the best way to cache Database queries in Laravel 5.1:

```
$value = Cache::remember('Categories', 60, function() {
    return \App\Models\Skill\Category_Model::paginate(1);
});
```

If the item does not exist in the cache, the **Closure** passed to the `remember` method will be executed and its result will be placed in the cache.

You may also combine the `remember` and `forever` methods, like what you used to do with 4.2 as part of eloquent itself:

```
$value = Cache::rememberForever('Categories', function() {
    return \App\Models\Skill\Category_Model::paginate(1);
});
```

Since you are using pagination you might want to add postfix to your caching keys like `Categories_1`